# How To Keep Background Image From Moving While Minimizing?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I've looked for solutions but they're only for if someone is scrolling. I, however, need a solution where the background image doesn't move while minimizing the browser window, clipping it.

Full Screen
[image]

Minimized Screen
[image]

When I minimize the window I'd like it not to flex with the browser. So in this example when I minimize, only the 'va' from 'vampire' would be shown.

Ex:

Full Screen(All Continents Showing)
[image]

Minimized Screen(Only Some Continents Showing)
[image]

```css
.testing{
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.png?text=vampire');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% ;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid testing"></div>
```

Edit:
Thanks for the answers but not what I'm looking for so far (5/17/21 4:00pm PST)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
.testing{
    background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.png?text=vampire');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 500px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 800px;
  }
```

Answers given were close but for people running across this problem in the future set background-position a fixed number of px.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your background image `fixed` I would give it a position `0 0` so that it remains on that position when you resize your window.

```css
.testing{
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.png?text=vampire');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid testing"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this for the CSS.

```css
.testing {
       background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.png?text=vampire');
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: 100% ;
       background-attachment: fixed;
       height: 800px;
       background-position: top calc(200px - 20vw) right;
       background-size: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid testing"></div>
```